# Error when passing value from Visualforce to Visual Workflow?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component, visual-workflow

I'm trying to figure out an error im getting in a visualforce page where im trying to pass a selected value to a visual workflow sobject variable.  I'm getting the error:

> Error: Parameter "sov_RibbonClause" has wrong value type."

Below is my visualforce page code. Can someone help me understand this error?

```
<apex:page controller="RibbonClauseSearchControllerv2">  
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Back"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="You Selected" columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedRibbonClauses}" var="rc2">
                    <apex:column value="{!rc2.rc.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!rc2.rc.Text__c}"/>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>           

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <flow:interview name="Vf_page_value_flow" buttonLocation="top">
    <apex:param name="sov_RibbonClause" value="{!selectedRibbonClauses}" />
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the portion from the controller related to the selectedRibbonClauses variable

```
public class RibbonClauseSearchControllerv2 {

    // the results from the search. do not init the results or a blank rows show up initially on page load
    public List<RibbonClauseWrapper> searchResults {get;set;}
    // the categories that were checked/selected.
    public List<RibbonClauseWrapper> selectedRibbonClauses {
        get {
            if (selectedRibbonClauses == null) selectedRibbonClauses = new List<RibbonClauseWrapper>();
            return selectedRibbonClauses;
        }
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify the field type of selectedRibbonClauses in the controller and the value type of sov_RibbonClause in the flow?

Comment: Are you passing multiple records into the flow from a list view?  If so you need to pass them into a sObject collection, not a sObject variable.

Comment: I am trying to pass only a single value as an sObject variable from a record that is selected from a query on the visualforce page.  I tried a couple different  things.  When I hardcode in an Id for the field in the VF page, the value comes through correctly in the flow.  (code at bottom of comment) But i still cant get it to come thru correctly when i select it in the Visualforce page.   `<apex:param name="vRibbonClauseId" value="a0hg0000001sMht" />`